# Append strings to pandas dataframe column with conditional

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm trying to achieve the following: check if each key value in the dictionary is in the string from column layers. If it meets the conditional, to append the value from the dictionary to the pandas dataframe.

For example, if BR and EWKS is contained within the layer, then in the new column there will be BRIDGE-EARTHWORKS.

**Dataframe**

```
mapping = {'IDs': [1244, 35673, 37863, 76373, 234298],
 'Layers': ['D-BR-PILECAPS-OUTLINE 2',
  'D-BR-STEEL-OUTLINE 2D-TERR-BOUNDARY',
  'D-SUBG-OTHER',
  'D-COMP-PAVE-CONC2',
  'D-EWKS-HINGE']}

df = pd.DataFrame(mapping)
```

**Dictionary**

```
d1 = {"BR": "Bridge", "EWKS": "Earthworks", "KERB": "Kerb", "TERR": "Terrain"}
```

**My code thus far is:**

```
for i in df.Layers 
  for x in d1.keys():
    first_key = list(d1)[0]
    first_val = list(d1.values())[0]
    print(first_key,first_val)
    if first_key in i:
      df1 = df1.append(first_val, ignore_index = True)
      # df.apply(first_val)
```

Note I'm thinking it may be easier to do the comprehension at the mapping step prior to creating the dataframe.. I'm rather new to python still so any tips are appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: can i see desired output of `df` to be precise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) for all matched keys, then mapping by dictionary with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and last aggregate `join`:

```
pat = r'({})'.format('|'.join(d1.keys()))
df['new'] = df['Layers'].str.extractall(pat)[0].map(d1).groupby(level=0).agg('-'.join)
print (df)
      IDs                               Layers             new
0    1244              D-BR-PILECAPS-OUTLINE 2          Bridge
1   35673  D-BR-STEEL-OUTLINE 2D-TERR-BOUNDARY  Bridge-Terrain
2   37863                         D-SUBG-OTHER             NaN
3   76373                    D-COMP-PAVE-CONC2             NaN
4  234298                         D-EWKS-HINGE      Earthworks
```